# How to replace a non English character with English character

Tags: java, python, php

I have got a weird problem. I'm getting text from Google cloud vision containing non English characters but they are actually English characters. It is a mistake from Google cloud vision OCR.

I'm getting a character like this : `Héllo`

`Notice that é is non English character.`

I want to convert into `simple "Hello"` so I can process this word.

I'm not looking for the programming answer. I'm just looking for ways to do this.

Any hint would be useful.

Thanks!

Comment: Please include some code!

Comment: I have no clue how to perform this task. That's why I had to post it here. I have got text from Google cloud vision. I don't know how am I supposed to do this. Just finding out ways to do this. Hope you understand. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Apache Commons is an option for you, you could make use of their StringUtils library. The [`stripAccents`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#stripAccents-java.lang.String-) method should suit your needs. From the source code you can see that it actually makes use of [`java.text.Normalizer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/text/Normalizer.html), so you could also look into that.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't know word "strip accents" I found the answer after searching from this word. 

Here is the answer for python: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517923/what-is-the-best-way-to-remove-accents-in-a-python-unicode-string